# How to redeploy a web service on SharePoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I've created a test web service and successfully deployed it to SharePoint 2007.  Now I actually need to put real code in the service and redeploy to the server.  I've rebuilt my dll and copied it to the appropriate bin and then re-gac'ed it - same steps taken to deploy in the first place.  However, when i access the services description page it will not display the new service methods that I've added in the new DLL.  How do I undeploy the old version and redeploy my new version?  Do I need to restart or reset IIS?

Thanks.

Comment: I just changed the name of the service and redeployed using the same procedure as before.  Now, of course I get the "Could not load type" error.  Somehow that dll is cached or in memory maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your dll in the GAC, then yes, you'll need to do an IISRESET whenever you replace it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are putting the assembly both in the BIN folder and GAC. Follow these steps to make sure you do not have an old version hanging around:

1. Remove assembly from all BIN folders of the SharePoint web application
2. Remove assembly from GAC and check that it has been removed
3. Put the new assembly into reflector and check that the code is really updated
4. Put the new assembly into the GAC
5. Run an IISRESET